# EntryProcessor without locking entries

Tags: hazelcast

In my application, I'm trying to process data in IMap, the scenario is as follows:

1. application recieves request (REST for example) with set of keys to be processed
2. application processes entries with given key and returns result - map where key is original key of the entry and result is calculated

for this scenario `IMap.executeOnKeys` is almost perfect, with one problem - the entry is locked while being processed - and really it hurts thruput. The IMap is populated on startup and never modified.

Is it possible to process entries without locking them? If possible without sending entries to another node and without causing network overhead (sending 1000 tasks to single node in for-loop)

Here is reference implementation to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

        IMap<String, String> map = instance.getMap("the-map");

        // populated once on startup, never modified
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            map.put("key-" + i, "value-" + i);
        }

        Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>();
        keys.add("key-1");  // every requst may have different key set, they may overlap

        System.out.println(" ---- processing ----");
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
        // to simulate parallel requests on the same entry
        pool.execute(() -> map.executeOnKeys(keys, new MyEntryProcessor("first")));
        pool.execute(() -> map.executeOnKeys(keys, new MyEntryProcessor("second")));

        System.out.println(" ---- pool is waiting ----");
        pool.shutdown();
        pool.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        System.out.println(" ------ DONE -------");
    }

    static class MyEntryProcessor implements EntryProcessor<String, String> {
        private String name;

        MyEntryProcessor(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public Object process(Map.Entry<String, String> entry) {
            System.out.println(name + " is processing " + entry);
            return calculate(entry); // may take some time, doesn't modify entry
        }

        @Override
        public EntryBackupProcessor<String, String> getBackupProcessor() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In executeOnKeys the entries are not locked. Maybe you mean that the processing happens on partitionThreads, so that there may be no other processing for the particular key? Anyhow, here's the solution:

Your EntryProcessor should implement:

- **Offloadable** interface -> this means that the partition-thread will be used only for reading the value. The calculation will be done in the offloading thread-pool.
- **ReadOnly** interface -> in this case the EP won't hop on the partition-thread again to save the modification you might have done in the entry. Since your EP does not modify entries, this will increase the performance.

Comment: from `EntryProcessor` javadoc:
'At the time you receive it the entry is locked and not released until the EntryProcessor completes', and from `ReadOnly` and `Offloadable` javadoc:
Currently supported in: executeOnKey(..), submitToKey(..)
Implementing these interfaces and using executeOnKey() the application is working, but I need to use Set of keys, no one at a time

Comment: Basically all partitions are divided such that one partition thread owns several partitions. So if a partition operation arrives, it is executed by its owner thread and while the thread is executing this operation, it will not accept any other operation. This in a way provides your code safe access to the key that it the entry will not be modified while your code is being executed.

Comment: And if you are after higher throughput, using Offloadable should certainly help. Agreed that its not currently available for executeOnKeys but firing multiple Offloadable EPs for all your keys may give you better throughput than what you are getting at the moment.

Comment: @wildnez does this mean that two operations which traditionally occur in-order using EntryProcessor will actually execute in-order if they are offloaded? For example, is there a chance one offloaded thread runs slower than the other?